# Can't access parental control email address

Tags: hearthstone

I'm not sure if this is the right place to post this but I want to buy some hearthstone packs but it says Parental controls restrict even though I have never set up parental controls on the account. I followed the link to retrieving the parental controls email address but it asked me for my parental control email address even though I have never created one. I tried putting in my email and I also tried putting in my battle.net username but it didn't work.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

According to https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/adding-and-removing-battlenet-parental-controls

> **Remove Parental Controls**
>
> To instantly allow an account with Parental Controls full access to our games and in-game shops, simply disable any restrictions in the Parental Controls dashboard. If you lost the email that gives you access to the Parental Controls Dashboard, you can [send yourself a new one](https://us.battle.net/account/parental-controls/retrieve.html). To completely remove Parental Controls from an account, please [contact us](https://us.battle.net/support/help/topic/battlenet/327).

Note that this doesn't apply to Hearthstone on iPad.  If you're playing the iPad version of Hearthstone, only your device's parental control settings apply, not your battle.net settings!